# How to get soap Action in client side

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui

Below is the java program i have written in the client side to receive & encrypt part of the XML message that is sent in the SOAP interface.

```
    SOAPBindingMessageContext soapbindingmessagecontext = (SOAPBindingMessageContext) iContext;
    javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage soapMessage = soapbindingmessagecontext.getRequestMessage();
    Iterator iterator = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().getAllHeaders();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) { 
        MimeHeader header = (MimeHeader) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(header.getName());
        System.out.println(header.getValue().toString());
        if (header.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("SOAPAction")) {
            System.out.println("The soapAction is  : " + header.toString());
            operationName = header.getValue().replaceAll("\"", "");
        }
    }
    if (debug) {
        System.out.println(operationName);
    }
```

However it looks like the operationName (soapAction in the WSDL) is null & not being extracted from the SOAP Message. I have confirmed from the logs that other MIME-headers can be extracted. Just the soapAction i am not able to extract. I have also confirmed from the soapUI that the soapAction is really sent and is not null when sending. Below is the snap of same. Could you please help me to understand where i am doing wrong ? 
[image]

Comment: Where do you need it i.e., which client ?  In SoapUI? Where / How are you running the above java code?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do partial message encryption for OSB web services running in weblogic. [link] (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/owsm/extensibility/owsm-extensibility-samples.htm#CIHIFCCE) .  So, as part of OWSM, we could write custom java-code to receive messages from different consumers and encrpt only part of it (more information can be found in the link i have shared). 

The above java-code will be deployed as a jar to weblogic and will be executed when there is a request coming in to the web-services.